# How to get the value from a flat list

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am using a flat list, and inside it a dropdown. While selecting a dropdown value in a particular row index, the dropdown will get changed. How do I get the particular row value which I've changed in the dropdown?

```js
<FlatList   
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.unit + index}
    extraData={this.state.residentList}
    onViewableItemsChanged={}
    renderItem={({ item ,index}) =>
        <Card style={{height:100}}>
            <View style={{height: 1, backgroundColor: 'lightgray'}}/>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row',flex:1}}>
                    <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <View Style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                        <Text style={styles.textDetails}>{`ddd: ${item.a1}`}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.textDetails}>{`rrr: ${item.b1}`}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.textDetails}>{`rr1: ${item.c1}`}</Text>

                    </View>
                    </View>

            <View style={{flex:0.5,marginRight:30}}>

                {item.role == 'xyz' ? this.selectRole(): <Text>       </Text> }

            </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{height: 1, backgroundColor: 'lightgray'}}/>
        </Card>
    }  
/>
```